# Unauthorised users to view homepage without menu

Tags: users

I have installed the [Front Page](https://www.drupal.org/project/front) module on my site. 
I want to show visitors (not-logged in users) to see the same homepage as logged in users but without the navigational bar.

I have used re-direct to the "/home" in the front page settings and removed menu permission in the anonymous users roles section but I am getting an access denied message.

Comment: I read online to create a page.tpl.php alias, remove the menu from it and attach/use that one for that page ONLY in the re-direct option of front page module

Comment: Try with [Context](https://www.drupal.org/project/context) module. With it you can remove blocks when certain conditions are met.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new template for your front page name it `page--front.tpl.php`

Create a variable which assign a role to a temporary variable in your `template_preprocess_page(&$vars)` like

```
function THEMENAME_preprocess_page(&$vars) {
  global $user  
  if(drupal_is_front_page()) {
   if(in_array('anonymous', $user->roles)) {
      $vars['navigation'] = false;
    }
  }
}
```

then in you `page--front.tpl.php` just check `if($vavigation) ..`